# select the top ID from a list of IDs

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a list of ZIP codes and every zip Code is affected to many citis.
So every zip Code exists many times in the table "Zip Code" .
Now, with the list i want to find the zipeCodeid from the table(first ID for every Zip Code).
But with a simple select like this :

```
 SELECT  CODCODEPOSTAL,CODEPOSTALID
FROM [***].[dbo].[CODEPOSTAL]
where CODCODEPOSTAL in ( 3000
,2080) group by CODCODEPOSTAL,CODEPOSTALID order by CODCODEPOSTAL
```

This is the result: We will have for every zipCode many ZipCodeIds.

[image]

but i just want to select the top ZipCodeId for every Zip Code.

[image]

Any solution and Thanks

Comment: You should add an `ORDER BY` statement, otherwise, what defines what a "top zip code" is?

Comment: @Icemanind Hi, question modified

Answer (score 2):

Will the 'top' ZipCodeID always be the lowest number?

If so, try something like:

```
SELECT CODCODEPOSTAL, MIN(CodePostalID) as CodePOstalID
FROM ***.[dbo].ZipCode
where CODCODEPOSTAL in (***)
GROUP BY CODCODEPOSTAL
```

If not, give some sample data and let us know how you determine which is the 'top' ID.

Comment: Hi, question modified

Comment: @zarzou - have amended my answer with the field names from your edit. You need to group just by CODCODEPOSTAL and select MIN(CODEPOSTALID)